# scraping in python, selector returns empty list

Tags: python, xpath, beautifulsoup, scrapy

Now its been 3 days I am torturing my brain for this. so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Coming to the problem I want to scrape flipkart.com, I have used scrapy before same problem occurs,s

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as ureq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = 'https://www.flipkart.com/offers-list/top-selling-mobiles?screen=dynamic&pk=themeViews%3DTopsellers-Mobiles-March18%3ADesk~widgetType%3DdealCard~contentType%3Dneo&wid=8.dealCard.OMU&otracker=clp_omu_Top%2BSelling%2BMobiles_mobile-phones-store_7'
uclient = ureq(url)
page_html = uclient.read()
uclient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')
container = page_soup.find_all("div", {"class":"MDGhAp"})
```

container should return bunch of objects instead of a empty list.
I want to click on every smartphone so the text can be extracted.
what am I doing wrong, can anyone guess.

Comment: there are no tags of `class = "MDGhAp"` in the html source

Comment: You'd have to use another means since the page is dynamic. Selenium is option or [requests-html](https://html.python-requests.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you didn't notice that you website is being rendered by javascript.

If you want your project successful there are multiple ways to do that.

First, 
Find out the `network call`  {API} that brings the desired data and mock that call in your project.

Second, Use `splash` or or other javascript render tools to get `js rendered` html in you response.

Answer (score 0):

If you go with Selenium, it'll return back 12 elements in the container.

```
import bs4 
from selenium import webdriver 


url = 'https://www.flipkart.com/offers-list/top-selling-mobiles?screen=dynamic&pk=themeViews%3DTopsellers-Mobiles-March18%3ADesk~widgetType%3DdealCard~contentType%3Dneo&wid=8.dealCard.OMU&otracker=clp_omu_Top%2BSelling%2BMobiles_mobile-phones-store_7'

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get(url)

html = browser.page_source
page_soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

container = page_soup.find_all("div", {"class":"MDGhAp"})
```

Now you can start extracting text from each element:

```
for element in container:
    print(element.text.strip())
```

**Output:**

```
Asus Zenfone Max Pro M2Upto 6GB RAM|64GB ROMFrom ₹12,999
Redmi Note 6 ProUpto 6GB RAM|64GB ROMFrom ₹13,999
Realme C16.2" Notch DisplayNow ₹7,499
Asus Zenfone Max M2Upto 4GB RAM|64GB ROMFrom ₹9,999
Honor 9N13MP+2MP |16MP CameraFrom ₹8,999
Realme 2 Pro3500 mAh BatteryFrom ₹13,990
Nokia 5.1 Plus 13MP+5MP | 8MP CameraNow ₹9,999
Realme 2Upto 4GB RAM|64GB ROMFrom ₹8,990
Google Pixel 35.5" FHD+ DisplayFrom ₹71,000
Redmi 612MP+5MP|5MP CameraFrom ₹8,499
Samsung Galaxy On64 GB RAM | 64 GB ROMNow ₹12,990
Nokia 6.1 Plus (4GB, 64 GB) 16MP+5MP Rear CameraNow ₹14,999
```